# Extract regex in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, series

Hi I'm looking to get the number of pieces from different products from a Df column into one new column. For now the numbers comes after the type of product.

The data looks like this:

```
PRODUCTS
PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 TAB RECUB
LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB
LOFTYL 150 MG ORAL 30 TAB
SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB
LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL 
*Keeps going more entries...*
```

My function looks like this:

```
df['PZ'] = df['PRODUCTS'].str.extract('([\d]*\.*[\d]+)\s*[tab|cap|grag|past|sob]',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Products could be  [TAB,COMP,AMP, SOB, PAST, GRAG ... and others]

And I want to get something like this:

```
PRODUCTS                              PZ
PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 TAB RECUB     30
LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB         15
LOFTYL 150 MG ORAL 30 TAB             30
SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB    10
LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL             30
```

What can I change in my line to get as follows?

Thank you for reading me and your help.

Comment: How `SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB` matches `'([\d]*\.*[\d]+)\s*[tab|cap|grag|past|sob]'` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'PRODUCTS':['PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 TAB RECUB','LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB','LOFTYL 150 MG ORAL 30 TAB','SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB','LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL']})
rx = r'(?i)(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?:tab|cap|grag|past|sob|comp)'
df['PZ'] = df['PRODUCTS'].str.extract(rx)
>>> df
                             PRODUCTS  PZ
0   PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 TAB RECUB  30
1       LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB  15
2           LOFTYL 150 MG ORAL 30 TAB  30
3  SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB  10
4           LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL  30
>>>
```

If the words like `tab`, `cap`, etc. are *whole words* and cannot be parts of longer words, you need to add a word boundary at the end of the pattern, i.e. `rx = r'(?i)(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?:tab|cap|grag|past|sob|comp)\b'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PoEveB/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive inline modifier
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1: zero or more digits, an optional `.` and then one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(?:tab|cap|grag|past|sob|comp)` - a non-capturing group (so as not to interfere with `Series.str.extract` output) matching any of the alternative substrings inside it
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe..**

Given a dataframe of (Note: I made the product appear twice for one row as an example in case this may happen)...

```
    PRODUCTS
0   PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 GRAG RECUB
1   LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB
2   LOFTYL 150 GRAG ORAL 30 TAB
3   SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB
4   LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL
5   *Keeps going more entries...*
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'PRODUCTS' : ["PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 GRAG RECUB", "LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB", \
                      "LOFTYL 150 GRAG ORAL 30 TAB", "SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB", \
                      "LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL" , "*Keeps going more entries...*"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# maintain a list of products to find
products = ['TAB', 'COMP', 'AMP', 'SOB', 'PAST', 'GRAG']

def getProduct(x):
    found = list()
    for product in products:
        pattern = r'(\d+)' + ' ' + str(product)
        found.append(re.findall(pattern, x))
    found = list(filter(None, found))
    found = [item for sublist in found for item in sublist]
    found = ", ".join(str(item) for item in found)
    return found

df['PZ'] = [getProduct(row) for row in df['PRODUCTS']]

print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    PRODUCTS                            PZ
0   PULSAR AT 20 MG ORAL 30 GRAG RECUB  30
1   LIPITOR 40 MG 1+1 ORAL 15 TAB       15
2   LOFTYL 150 GRAG ORAL 30 TAB         30, 150
3   SOMAZINA 500 MG ORAL 10 COMP RECUB  10
4   LOFTYL 30 TAB 150 MG ORAL           30
5   *Keeps going more entries...*
```